# scheduling job in php

Tags: php, cron

there is a facebook app which I'm writing , Users grant offline_access to the program .
I need to collect information about them for example twice a day at 12 am and pm .

how should I do this in PHP?
should I use cron jobs in linux/windows or what?

Answer (score 3):

Yep. If you can, do use them. There would be other solutions, like having the first user hitting your site after xx hours run those same scripts but the solutions would be cumbersome and less-than-ideal.

**Cron is the way to go.**

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you foresee the need to run a variety of other crons, would be to use the [Zend Server Job Queue](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/zend-server-job-queue) system.